# How to Ingest data into Azure data explorer from the Azure Table Storage source without Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-data-explorer

I'm new to Azure Data Explorer. Here I need to migrate the data from Azure Table Storage table data into Azure Data Explorer Cluster's Database's Table without using Azure Data Factory.
May be if able to do programatically using .NET, kindly suggest it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **(1)** How much data? **(2)** Why do you rule out ADF? **(3)** Have you searched on-line for .NET support for Azure Table Storage and/or Azure Storage Explorer? It's there. **(4)** [Azcopy with Table support (v7.3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#azcopy-with-table-support-v73) **(5)** Azure Storage Explorer

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz: Kindly find the answers below, 1. Crores level data 2. Expensive service 3. Yes. But, couldn't get sample code to ingest into Azure data explorer. 4 & 5. Since its Azure Data Explorer Azcopy not helping to use.

Comment: **(2)** It would probably cost you a few dollars top. **(3)** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/net-sdk-ingest-data **(4)+(5)** These are for the export. Once you have the data in a file you can easily load it to ADX from your computer or Azure Storage Blob, using the [Kusto Web Explorer OneClick](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/oneclick).  From Azure Storage you can also use the [.ingest into table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-storage) command